# How to autoplay iframe with video in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, iframe

I googled answer and didn't find any for this. How can you autoplay videos in chrome. This is what I have tried:

```
<iframe allow="fullscreen; autoplay" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found answer in internet but not in stackoverflow so I would leave it here so someone can find it:

```
        <iframe allow="autoplay *; fullscreen *" allowfullscreen="true" 
          src="https://example.com">
        </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's surprisingly little info on this around. After much searching, I found this to work.

> To modify the code to include an autoplay function, simply insert this
>   after the alphanumeric code:
>
> ```
> ?rel=0;&autoplay=1
> ```

Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iG9CE55wbtY?rel=0;&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Reference: https://support.gospacecraft.com/hc/en-us/articles/202694610-Set-Video-to-Autoplay

Answer (score 0):

simply add autoplay function to your code: "?autoplay=1" after the link  (inside the double quotation marks).

```
<iframe src="https://example.com?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

refer [this will explain you better.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkIabnfvJI8)

Answer (score 0):

In order to autoplay a video, the iframe needs to include autoplay=1 in the src property and allow=autoplay property as well.

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com?autoplay=1" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```